# Помогите дописать конвертор php в html

Tags: php

Есть код, который копирует из одной папки содержимое в другую. Так же есть код, который исходный php конвертирует в конечный, статический html. Хочу их объединить, но что то не получается.

Вот код, который все копирует.

```
function recursive_files_copy($source_dir, $destination_dir){
  // Open the source folder / directory
  $dir = opendir($source_dir);

  // Create a destination folder / directory if not exist
  @mkdir($destination_dir);

  // Loop through the files in source directory
  while($file = readdir($dir))
  {
    // Skip . and ..
    if(($file != '.') && ($file != '..') && ($file != 'includes') && (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != 'php'))
    {
      // Check if it's folder / directory or file
      if(is_dir($source_dir.'/'.$file))
      {
        // Recursively calling this function for sub directory
        recursive_files_copy($source_dir.'/'.$file, $destination_dir.'/'.$file);
      }
      else
      {
        // Copying the files
        copy($source_dir.'/'.$file, $destination_dir.'/'.$file);
      }
    }
  }

  closedir($dir);
  // convertphp();
}

$source_dir = "D:\openserver\domains\test1.com";

$destination_dir = "D:\openserver\domains\test2.com";

recursive_files_copy($source_dir, $destination_dir);
```

А вот код, которые конвертирует все в html:

```
ob_start();
include "../pf.com/index.php";
$php_to_html = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents("index.html", $php_to_html);
```

Но в нем нужно вручную запрашивать файл и ставить его куда нужно. Хочу этот код внедрить в верхний, чтобы все делалось автоматически. Пытался делать так:

```
function recursive_files_copy($source_dir, $destination_dir){
  // Open the source folder / directory
  $dir = opendir($source_dir);

  // Create a destination folder / directory if not exist
  @mkdir($destination_dir);

  // Loop through the files in source directory
  while($file = readdir($dir))
  {
    // Skip . and ..
    if(($file != '.') && ($file != '..') && ($file != 'includes') && (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != 'php'))
    {
      // Check if it's folder / directory or file
      if(is_dir($source_dir.'/'.$file))
      {
        // Recursively calling this function for sub directory
        recursive_files_copy($source_dir.'/'.$file, $destination_dir.'/'.$file);
      }
      else
      {
        // Copying the files
        copy($source_dir.'/'.$file, $destination_dir.'/'.$file);
      }
//////////////
    }else if(($file != 'includes') && (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'php')){
      ob_start();
      include $file;
      $file = ob_get_clean();
      copy($source_dir.'/'.$file, $destination_dir.'/'.$file);
    }
//////////////
  }

  closedir($dir);
  // convertphp();
}
$source_dir = "D:\openserver\domains\test1.com";

$destination_dir = "D:\openserver\domains\test2.com";

recursive_files_copy($source_dir, $destination_dir);
```

Но где то допускаю ошибку.

Текст ошибки:

```
Warning: copy(D:\openserver\domains\test.com/
Warning: include(index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\OpenServer\domains\test2.com\copy.php on line 28

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'index.php' for inclusion (include_path='.') in D:\OpenServer\domains\test2.com\copy.php on line 28
): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\OpenServer\domains\test2.com\copy.php on line 30
```

Comment: И нам нужно угадать, что за ошибку вы получаете и что вам нужно изменить чтобы код заработал "как надо"? Рекомендую почитать [Справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) о том, как лучше задавать вопросы.

Comment: Я просто забыл код ошибки написать, зачем сразу справками закидывать меня?) Обновил основной вопрос.

Comment: Проблема в том что вы используете относительный путь для включения файла index.php, о чём и говорит вам эта ошибка. Используйте абсолютный путь, либо копируйте файл в каждую директорию, и удалите относительный путь.

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг кому то нужно будет, то итоговый результат вот. Если есть пожелания по улучшению или оптимизации, пишите.

Если вкратце, то скрипт берет и копирует все, кроме папки inludes(внутри header.php, footer.php и т д), и других скриптов для с расширением php, а это основные страницы(index.php, about.php, contacts.php).

Спросите для чего это? Все просто. Вы можете удобно работать со всеми повторяющимися элементами (header.php, footer.php и т д), просто добавив их в папку includes, и в самих страницах добавлять через:

`<?php include 'includes/header.php' ?>`

А затем, когда все будет готово, с помощью скрипта сгенерировать статический html/css/js сайт и загрузить его на тот же github pages. Важно понимать, что github pages не начнет понимать php, этот все просто чтобы облегчить разработку статического html/css/js сайта.

!!!**Скрипт должен находиться в той же папке, где вы хотите, что бы в итоге у вас был ваш статический сайт**!!!

Затем чтобы запустить скрипт, в консоли перейдите в папку со скриптом и запустите его с помощью команды :

```
php copy.php
```

```
<?php
$source_dir = "D:\openserver\domains\source.com";

$destination_dir = "D:\openserver\domains\destination.com";

recursive_files_copy($source_dir, $destination_dir);

function recursive_files_copy($source_dir, $destination_dir)
{
    // Open the source folder / directory
    $dir = opendir($source_dir);

    // Create a destination folder / directory if not exist
    @mkdir($destination_dir);

    // Loop through the files in source directory
    while ($file = readdir($dir))
    {
        // Skip . and ..
        if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..') && ($file != 'includes') && (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != 'php'))
        {
            // Check if it's folder / directory or file
            if (is_dir($source_dir . '/' . $file))
            {
                // Recursively calling this function for sub directory
                recursive_files_copy($source_dir . '/' . $file, $destination_dir . '/' . $file);
            }
            else
            {
                // Copying the files
                copy($source_dir . '/' . $file, $destination_dir . '/' . $file);
            }
        }
        else if ((!is_dir($source_dir . '/' . $file)) && (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'php'))
        {
            ob_start();
            include $source_dir . '/' . $file;
            $php_to_html = ob_get_clean();
            $fp = fopen($file, "w");
            fwrite($fp, $php_to_html);
            fclose($fp);
            rename(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME) , pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '.html');
        }
    }

    closedir($dir);
    // convertphp();
    
}
?>
```